# Draw ellipse using GMap.net in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, coordinate-systems

I want to draw an ellipse given two locations in lat/long coordinates. I want these two locations to be the focal points of the curve. How can I do this with the library? Are there any formulas to create the ellipse required without the functions of Gmap.net?

Comment: Are you trying to create the ellipse with or without Gmap.net? Or with both?

Comment: Both, the library is a great tool, but I also want to know the principles behind to recreate the method by my own.